# Foundation Joyride issue in IE9

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I am using foundation's joyride plugin, everything is working fine in Chrome and FF, but in ie9
the highlighted element is clickable.

Ex. I am highlighting a form's submit button like "When you are done, Click this Button to Register" when I click the highlighted button the submit action takes place in IE9 browser.

But it is working fine in Chrome and FF, when in click the highlighted Submit button nothing happens.

Is there any way to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Are there javascript errors ?

Comment: No, I didnt get any js errors

Comment: Can you put your code please

Comment: This issue is happening in whole application, the joyride highlights are editable in ie 9 and 10.
I think there has to be some additional configuration for ie