# Foundation Joyride issue in IE 10 - Highlighted button not visible

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I am using Foundation's joyride plugin, everything is working fine in chrome and ff, as usual ie is messing in some areas.
I am highlighting a save button like after completing the form click this button to submit.
But that button is not visible in ie10, when the joyride highlights that button.

I dint get any js errors in my console

Strange thing is that when I open the ie 10 developer console the button is displayed.

please help me fix this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foundation Joyride issue in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101698/foundation-joyride-issue-in-ie9)

Comment: hi, general this is not duplicate question, both are different question and both are asked by me.
But yes both are related to foundation's joyride